# How to Add Http Hearders for AWS S3 images

Tags: php, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers

Here is my code

```
function s3UploadImage($tmpFile,$file) {
     $tmpLoc=$bucket.$file;
    $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    $s3->putBucket($bucket, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
    if($s3->putObjectFile($tmpFile, $bucket , $tmpLoc, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(
                 "Cache-Control" => "max-age=94608000",
                 "Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", 
                              strtotime("+3 years")),$contentType) )
    {
        $msg = "S3 Upload Successful.";
    //  $s3file='https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx/'.$tmpLoc;
    $s3file='https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx/'.$tmpLoc;
//              echo "<img src='$s3file'/>";
                echo 'S3 File URL:'.$s3file;
        $status=true;
    }
    else{
        $msg = "S3 Upload Fail.";
        $status=false;
    }
    return $status;
}
```

In this code i added array("Cache-Control" => "max-age=31536000","Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+3 years")) its working fine only. But its adding like this

```
  x-amz-meta-cache-control  public,max-age=31536000
    x-amz-meta-expires  Wed, 11 Dec 2017 10:47:59 GMT
```

In google page speed test tool still it showing expires not specified
but if i add directly http Header in s3 using some tools like s3 browser . its working fine.Its adding like this

```
Expires Wed, 15 May 2019 20:00:00
Cache-Control   max-age=31536000, public
```

using api how to add like this http Headers.

Answer (score 3):

Here the headers you added is like custom meta data. While creating a custom meta data your SDK will append x-amz-meta- along with your meta data key to identify it. 
You have to set this header as,

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
    'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
    'Expires'      => 'Wed, 15 May 2019 20:00:00',
    'CacheControl' => 'max-age=31536000, public',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'Metadata'     => array(    
        'param1' => 'value 1',
        'param2' => 'value 2'
     )
));
```

Comment: This is valid, confirmed 7/25/2019.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I solved that problem like this check my below code

```
$metaHeaders = array();
$requestHeaders['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=31536000';
$requestHeaders['Expires'] = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+1 years"));


 if($s3->putObject($tmpFile, $bucket , $tmpLoc, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, $metaHeaders, $requestHeaders)
```

use `putObject` method instead of `putObjectFile` method and set `$requestHeaders` 
this works